# how to copy file around 11GB in size in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, clipboard

I have big problem with my server. It is not starting the OS. Now I am using Ubuntu by booting from the DVD to copy all data in the server. But, I cannot copy one file which is around 11 GB. That file is very important.

I believe I may be unable to copy this file because it is larger than 4.3 GB.

How can I copy this big file?

Comment: Use an external harddrive

Comment: what is file system of the disk your are copying to?

Comment: What is the error message? Why can't you copy this file? Why do you believe it has to do with the size of the file?

Comment: Get yourself an external USB disk (for example a 2.5" disk, they only need one USB cable to connect, and 500G cheap as dirt).  Connect it to your server, and reformat it as ext4.  (Use gparted, or whatever you are used to)  When you're done, mount the disk, and copy way you want.  The issue, as Web-E correctly assumes, is that you're trying to copy to a FAT32 filesystem.  That filesystem allows files of a maximum size of a bit more than 4GB.  Other filesystems do not have such restrictions, hence I tell you to use ext4.  (Below, someone recomments HTFS, but he most certainly means NTFS)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to see whether the 11GB compresses well enough using gzip to get it down to smaller than 4GB.  Depending on the data in the file, this might work.  Wouldn't count on it, but it's a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

try with cpio :

```
cpio -dump destination < origin
```

Comment: can you give me for example this type

Comment: cpio -dump /some/mount/point < you_big_file.ext

Comment: ex : i have 2 volume with name new and old, now i want to copy file new/data/idocweb.nfs   to old

Comment: your destination is then new/data/idocweb.nfs and the origin is old/data/idocweb.nfs.

Comment: origin is new/data/idocweb.nfs   destination is  old. file idocweb.nfs is database form lotus note. it has 11Gb

Comment: My server is IBM have 4 HDD user raid 5. Now my server have dump OS windows server 2008. i use Ubuntu desktop 12.04 build on DVD to bootting to saving data on HDD server. I use USB HDD with 1Tb capacity connect with server

Comment: i got real difficulties trying to understand your last comment. As said, cpio is like cp, but doing "cp from to", type "cpio -dump to < from". Note that large copy over USB may be unstable.

Comment: wow, "Note that large copy over USB may be unstable". My server is Broken OS. I just only connect USB with NTSF format to copy data. Why unstable? how to resolution backup data with larger capacity

Comment: Just try it, if cpio complete, you may be good. if the external disk stop responding before cpio complete, you may have to find a way to slow down transfer. Anyway, try ..

Comment: oke, i try it. Now i have been download Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, and then, build it to DVD, tomorrow i will try it. Thanks your comments. I'm from Vietnam and working in Petrovietnam Oil and Gas Group

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the command rsync for this. Many backup systems are based on it.

```
rsync -av from to
```

Just exchange "from" with the name of the file and "to" with the directory where you want to copy the file to.

It is very usefull for incremental backup and have been ported to different OS:es.  If you want to make a backup of a directory, you just use the directory instead of "from". For more information, you could try the online manual pages. Just use these commands

```
man rsync
man cpio
```

or even

```
man man
```

Good luck.

Comment: `man man` O.o that's messing with my mind

Comment: i want to copy the file in volume OLD with folder IBM/data/idocweb.nfs to destination USB HDD. This file idocweb.nfs have 11Gb. What can i do?

Comment: someone help me

Comment: jackweirdy, you must have a man page for the man view command to. And no, there are no man page for men and women. :)

Tonytruong, have you read the man page?  Yes, you can copy large files with `rsync`, it's what it was written to do.  So it should be no problem.
Just do as we described `cpio` and `rsync` here. Use `rsync -av` and just add the path to the file idocweb.nfs and the directory where you find tha USB HDD (you might find it under `/media/` directory).
You have not given enough information to help you more.  Like where the HDD is and where you find OLD (also under `/media/`?)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the command you use to copy the file.

You need to reformat the drive into HTFS. Then any way of copying would work.